# Data validation in backend services

Tags: validation, spring-boot, backend

I have created a backend code in spring-boot for an android app.

My question, is there any rule for distinguishing between the validations at backend side or at frontend side?

For example- for user creation blank fields should be only checked at the frontend side but for testing backend services alone is it okay to have validations on the backend side.

If we just do validations at the frontend side then the problem arises when we test backend services alone.

Answer (score 1):

As general rule, data sent from the client cannot be trusted. E.g. even if the client validated a field is not null, you should assume that field was not validated at all.

You should implement similar validation logic on the backend as well.
[Here's the starting point](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#validation-beanvalidation) for implementing validation with Spring, based on [JSR-303](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not only "ok" to have validation on the backend but it's required. As @hovanessyan mentioned, you can never trust the data from the client. Never.

As a rule of thumb, APIs need to be bullet proof. All the edge cases (null-safety, type-safety, min/max, custom validations) should be covered and tested. There's nothing worse than an API responding with a 500.

Lots of devs noticed that there's a bit of validation logic duplication between frontend and backend and this is one of the reasons technologies like Node.js became so popular - you could in theory share the validations.

Also, don't be discouraged by having to duplicate your validation logic. It's tedious but necessary.